# React hook - useEffect missing dependencies warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am not sure if this is a valid warning by using `useEffect` around the dependency array, it seems like whenever variable, method or dispatch inside the `useEffect` are giving warning that
**React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'active', 'retrieveUser', and 'dispatch'. Either include them or remove the dependency array** of following example, if I just leave it as blank array to perform the `componentDidMount` functionality

```js
useEffect(() => {
   setActive(active);   
   await retrieveUser(param1, param2);
   dispatch(someAction);
}, []).        // warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'active', 'retrieveUser', 'param1', 'param2', and 'dispatch'. Either include them or remove the dependency array, but here I just want to perform componentDidMount concept so my dependency list has to be empty
```

or

```js
useEffect(() => {
   await retrieveUser(param1, param2);
   dispatch(someAction);
}, [userId]).   // warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'retrieveUser', 'param1', 'param2', and 'dispatch'. Either include them or remove the dependency array
```

Are those valid warning? Especially that I just want to monitor on specific data field, what's the point of adding all inside dispatch or method into the dependency array if I can't add anything into the dependency list(for componentDidMOunt) or I just want to monitor `userId`, not `param1`, `param2`, etc

Comment: What is the concern with adding those functions that won’t change such as dispatch?

Comment: dispatch is fine, but adding method into the dependency list makes me confusing, once I did that, my existed method has another warning to suggest using useCallback...also if my method includes some other parameters, e.g `await retrieveUser(param1, param2, param3)` it also suggest to add `param1, param2, param3`  into dependency list, but I just want to watch if `userId` changes, whether `param1` changes are should not fire the useEffect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is giving this warning because you are using part of your component's state or props in `useEffect` but have told it not to run the `useEffect` callback when that state/props changes. React assumes you will want to run that `useEffect()` whenever the referenced states change so it is giving you a warning. **If you were only referencing variables outside of state or props, you would not get this warning.** See below for info about conditionally running `useEffect`.

Since your goal is to only run `useEffect` only sometimes, you're likely going to need to restructure your component so that different data is in or out of state. It's difficult to recommend more specific solutions without knowing more about the component; but, a good goal is to have the state you utilize in `useEffect` match up with the changes that you want to trigger a rerender.

There might be other issues with state in your component. For example, I notice that you call `setActive(active);`. If active is part of the component's state, that means you are setting active to itself. Which isn't necessary. (this is assuming you are following typical naming patterns and likely have a line at the top of your component like:

`const [active, setActive] = useState(initialValue);`

---

**Conditionally running `useEffect`**

When you provide a second argument to `useEffect()`, it limits the situations when useEffect runs the callback function on rerenders. This is for performance reasons as explained in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

In the first `useEffect` where you provide an empty array, you are telling React to only run those actions (`setActive(active)`...etc.) when the component mounts and unmounts.

In the second `useEffect` where you provide an array with `userId`, you are telling React to only run the callback on mount, unmount, and whenever `userId` changes.

React is giving you that warning because it knows it won't run useEffect if `active`...etc or other values change. This can cause different parts of your component to be referencing different states. For example, one part of your component might be using `userId = 1` and another part is using `userId = 2`. This is not how React is designed to work.

Comment: What if one wants to retrieve only one userId from the API, when the component mounts? You could change the userId prop, but you don't want to automatically make a request every time. This sounds like the component is buggy, but there might be some valid use case for running a side effect using the initial prop or state only once.

Comment: Sorry I was not understanding here...As you already mentioned, if I removed the dependency list, the useEffect would fire on every re-render regardless any state value changes, that's not what I am looking for... I would like my useEffect run only at certain componentDidMount(with empty array) or componentDidUpdate/shoudUpdate(with field in array), my question would be, based on my existed attempt, why does it give the warning and how could I resolve this? e.g, if I didn't put anything in the array to perform componentDidMount, why is it giving time the warning to ask me add into the list?

Comment: @KevDing, can you include your whole component in your question to help us better understand your intentions?

Comment: @TylerAuer Sure, I have updated my question with concrete warning message, for example, if I pass an empty array to perform the componentDidMount, react is throwing me warning to asking me add stuff into the list, but I can't do it...adding stuff into the list or remove the ist would solve the warning, but it will never be a `componentDidMount` usage

Comment: @KevDing, are the dependencies React says are missing either part of your component's state or passed to your component as props?

Comment: yes, they are either from useState or from useSelector

Comment: Gotcha, that's why React is throwing that warning. If the variables (like `active`) are part of your component's state and you use them in useEffect, React assumes you will want to fire that useEffect callback whenever the state changes. It's warning you that won't happen because those state variables aren't listed as a dependency. The warning (probably) won't break your app, but it is likely a sign that you are structuring the component in an atypical way.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand that state value are suggested to be in the dep list, but what function or dispatch is also suggested to put in dev list? and when I put my function name inside dep list, there is a new warning on my function that it suggest to make it using usecallback

Comment: nvm, I have read something about this here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Create a hook that executes only once:

```
const useEffectOnce = effect => {
    useEffect(effect, []);
};
```

use this hook inside your component

```
useEffectOnce(() => {
    const request = async () => {
        const result = await retrieveSum(param1, param2);
        setResult(result);
    };

    request();
});
```

Now, even if your props (param1, param2) change, the effect is called only once. Be very careful when doing this, the component is probably buggy unless your initial props are truly special. I don't see how this is different from disabling the rule with

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-satoshi-fngrw?file=/src/App.js